# How do I assign different data-target to different option values so different models shows up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, model

I tried both switch cases and if else statements to get models with id accept, reject, review to show up but none is working for me. I just want to confirm if I am doing something wrong in terms of logic and syntax.

```
<select class="input-sm form-control" id="pendingbulk">
   <option value="0">Bulk Actions</option>
   <option value="1">Accept</option>
   <option value="2">Reject</option>
   <option value="3">Report</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="pendingapply" data-toggle="modal">Apply</button>
<script>
   $("#pendingapply").click(function() {
   var action = $('#pendingbulk').val();
   switch(parseInt(action)) {
   case 1:
     $(this).data("target") === "#accept";
     break;
   case 2:
     $(this).data("target") === "#reject";
     break;
   case 3:
     $(this).data("target") === "#report";
     break;
   default:
   });
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
   $("#pendingapply").click(function() {
   var action = $('#pendingbulk').val();
   if (action = 1) {
     $(this).data("target") === "#accept";
   } else if (action = 2) {
     $(this).data("target") === "#reject";
   } else if (action = 3) {
     $(this).data("target") === "#report";
   };
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Triple equals signs are for comparison. To set the data-target to those options, use single equals signs:

    $("#pendingapply").click(function() {
       var action = $('#pendingbulk').val();
       switch(parseInt(action)) {
       case 1:
         $(this).data("target") = "#accept";
         break;
       case 2:
         $(this).data("target") = "#reject";
         break;
       case 3:
         $(this).data("target") = "#report";
         break;
       default:
       });

Comment: I tried that before but it still doesn't work. Using data-target directly in the button works for me so I am guessing the script is not registering the data-target attribute onto the button?

Comment: if (action = 1) { will always be true as you just set it to 1.  You need to use == for comparison.

Comment: See my answer below.  In jQuery when you are setting a value, you pass it as a second parameter. You do not need to use `===`, `==`, or `=` at all.  But if were assigning a variable in javascript then, yes, you would use a single `=`.

Comment: I tried it on JsFiddle and none worked.

Comment: Can you point to your jsfiddle? It works for me with no problem.

Comment: Well if you tried it and your code actually called out different models then I guess it is my own scripting problem in the file. I will test more and see.

Comment: You might want to set `data-target="somevalue"` initially.  That way if your script fails it as least has some target...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#pendingapply").on('click', function() {
 var action = $('#pendingbulk').val();
 var $t=$(this);
 switch(parseInt(action)) {
 case 1:
   $t.attr("data-target","#accept" );
   break;
 case 2:
   $t.attr("data-target","#reject" );
   break;
 case 3:
   $t.attr("data-target","#report" );
   break;
 default:
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<select ng-model="pendingBulk" class="input-sm form-control" id="pendingbulk">
           <option value="0">Bulk Actions</option>
           <option value="1">Accept</option>
           <option value="2">Reject</option>
           <option value="3">Report</option>
        </select>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="pendingapply" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Apply</button>
```

Add the below div with three embedded forms each for accept, reject and report respectively inside the body of your HTML:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"></div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form name="Form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-controller="FormModalCtrl">
          <div class="form-group" ng-if="pendingBulk == 1">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="level">Enter number</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="number" id="level" class="form-control" ng-model="number" />
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group" ng-if="pendingBulk == 2">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="level">Enter number</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="number" id="level" class="form-control" ng-model="number" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group" ng-if="pendingBulk == 3">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="level">Enter number</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="number" id="level" class="form-control" ng-model="number" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </form>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```